# Magento 2 - Extend onepage.phtml to add custom JS

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

Magento 2

I have created a custom shipping method module and need to add custom JS to the checkout page where the shipping address and shipping method is set. But it is not working for me.

I have added my own `onepage.phtml` in the following location :

```
My_Module\view\frontend\templates\onepage.phtml
```

I also created a `checkout_index_index.xml` file in the following location :

```
My_Module\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml
```

The location of my JS :

```
My_Module\view\frontend\web\js\custom.js
```

The contents of my `onepage.phtml` file :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        require(['jquery', 'custom-js'], function($) {
            alert('JS loaded');
        });
</script>
```

Contents of my `checkout_index_index.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.onepage">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">My_Module::onepage.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Contents of my `requirejs-config.js` file:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            custom-js: 'My_Module/js/custom-js'
        }
    }
};
```

Contents of my `module.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="My_Module" setup_version="1.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
  </config>
```

When I add the contents of my `onepage.phtml` file to the core `onepage.phtml` file the JS is loaded correctly.

Also, when I change the `referenceBlock` `name` to `checkout.root` in the `checkout_index_index.xml` file, my JS files are loaded but it seems that only the `onepage.phtml` file is then rendered and nothing else... Am I using the wrong `name` value?

Is there a better way to include JS or am I just missing something? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: so alert message is not coming right when you change referenceBlock name to checkout.root am I right?

Comment: check the file names of js file

Comment: Managed to find solution: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/276642/magento-2-extend-onepage-phtml-to-add-custom-js